# Executing same task on two different inventory groups based on conditionals

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have a task in Ansible which needs to be executed on two different inventory groups based on certain condition.

Say if a specific flag is set, I want to execute it on one host. If the flag is disabled, it needs to be executed on the other. Is it possible to use conditionals for determining inventory set in which the task should run in Ansible? 
**Inventories:**

```
[group_A] 
A 
a 
[group_B] 
B 
b
```

**Task:**

```
-name: Stop component 
 roles: 
  -stop 
 hosts:
  -group_A, when: flag|bool 
  -group_B, when: not flag|bool
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: An easier option could be to use a variable like `- hosts: "{{ var }}"`, and then set it (with extra-vars) as `-e "var=group_A"` (or `group_B`) when running the playbook.

Answer (score 2):

For example

```yaml
shell> cat playbook
- hosts: "{{ flag|default(true)|bool|ternary('group_A', 'group_B') }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: inventory_hostname
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -e flag=True playbook.yml 

ok: [A] => 
  inventory_hostname: A
ok: [a] => 
  inventory_hostname: a
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -e flag=False playbook.yml 
ok: [B] => 
  inventory_hostname: B
ok: [b] => 
  inventory_hostname: b
```