# Refer a variable defined in group_vars/all.yml in playbook 'hosts' field

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-template

I have a variable *inventory_group_name* which represents an inventory group name and is initialized in *group_vars/all/all.yml*.

```
inventory_group_name: "group1"
```

**inventories**

```
[group1]
host1
host2
```

The code snippet is something similar to below.

```
- name: Check whether inventory name is picked properly
  hosts: {{ inventory_group_name }}
  tasks:
    - name: Debug statement
      debug:
        msg: "{{ inventory_group_name }}"
```

When I run the above, the value from all.yml is not being picked up by the playbook in *hosts* field and it throws an error as follows:

```
"ERROR! The field 'hosts' has an invalid value, which includes an undefined variable. The error was: 'inventory_group_name' is undefined"
```

However, the hosts value is picked up properly if it is overridden using extra-vars. The value in debug statement also picks value properly from all.yml.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd suggest avoiding complicated logic/ternary operations and variables to target hosts as a regular practice. There are ways to separate inventories, and target playbook to specific groups/hosts. As mentioned in [best practices](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html), a `webservers.yml` playbook targets the `webservers` group in the inventory.

Comment: Hi @seshadri_c- Thank you for your suggestion. I have been following this approach as suggested by you in another question of mine. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69447582/executing-same-task-on-two-different-inventory-groups-based-on-conditionals
The issue here is that the task will be executed only when a specific flag is set and in those cases I use extra-vars to override the variable to be used with hosts. Although the task is skipped when the flag is false, it throws an error that the variable is not defined as stated in the question. Thus I tried initializing it in group_vars/all

Comment: That suggestion was a simpler option to using flags (with ternary condition) to target hosts. Such approaches can be used if the use case really requires it. This could be like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/), and I encourage you to post the actual requirement/use case in the question.

Comment: You can't use a group variable at play level since ansible does not yet know which target it will have to connect to. Moreover, the var could have a different value depending on the target host. In other words: this will not work. You can use an extra var though in this situation.